# Loop and select

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables, select

I am currently trying to figure out how to loop for **variable** in column A and I want to select range from this cell to the last row with the 2 other column B and C (last row have the same variable).

I have tried

```
Sub TretourTdepart
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim X As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("data_(6)") 'Define sheet to copy from

    LastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row to copy from

    For X = 2 To LastRow
        If sh.Cells(X, 1) = "variable" Then
            Set Rng = Range(sh.Cells(LastRow, 1), sh.Cells(X, 1))
            Rng.Select
          End If
      Next
End Sub
```

but the above script doesn't select the range of cells as I wanted.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a helpful description of your problem - please elaborate. And read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: One thing is that your range only covers column 1. Shouldn't it be `sh.Cells(X, 3)` ?

Comment: There's no escape from the loop, put `Exit For` after `Rng.Select`

Comment: I have 3 columns (A=title,B=date and C= value). In column A, I found 2 variables (WaterMeter from the first row to the 1200 and ElectricityMeter from 1201 to the last Row). I want to select a range in column 1 with title "ElectricityMeter" to the last row, in case I want to select also the coulmn B and C With the coulumn A.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to loop, you can use the match function if your sheet is guaranteed to have the "variable" entry:

```
Sub TretourTdepart()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim VariRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set sh = Sheets("data_(6)") 'Define sheet to copy from

LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row to copy from
VariRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("variable", sh.Range("A:A"), 0)

Set rng = sh.Range(Cells(VariRow, 1), Cells(LastRow, 3))

End Sub
```

If the "variable" entry is not guaranteed to be there then you can wrap it in an `if` check:

**edit** I see in the comment your "variable" is actually a string so have set this as an actual variable `MyVariable`

```
Sub TretourTdepart()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim VariRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim MyVariable As String: MyVariable = "ElectricityMeter"

Set sh = Sheets("data_(6)") 'Define sheet to copy from

LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), MyVariable) > 0 Then
    VariRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MyVariable, sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
    Set rng = sh.Range(Cells(VariRow, 1), Cells(LastRow, 3))
End If

End Sub
```